# Como colocar hora e data em campos inputs com jQuery e jQuery UI?

Tags: jquery, html, css, css3, jquery-ui

Como fazer a inclusão dos arquivos de estilo e dos arquivos JavaScript do jQuery UI para que os inputs de data e hora mostrem perfeitamente os campos em pt_BR? É preciso modificar os atributos das bibliotecas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eis o código cujo os estilos podem ser colocados no header e as bibliotecas javascript juntamente com os códigos e atributos podem ser colocados no footer ou em arquivo externo e serve para qualquer sistema que use `html/css/javascript/jquery` para funcionar.

```
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.0/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.min.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="css/jquery.ui.timepicker.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.ui.timepicker.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(function(){

            jQuery('#timepicker').timepicker();
            jQuery('#datepicker').datepicker();

            /* Brazilian initialisation for the jQuery UI date picker plugin. */
            /* Written by Leonildo Costa Silva (leocsilva@gmail.com). */
            (function( factory ) {
                if ( typeof define === "function" && define.amd ) {

                    // AMD. Register as an anonymous module.
                    define([ "../datepicker" ], factory );
                } else {

                    // Browser globals
                    factory( jQuery.datepicker );
                }
            }(function( datepicker ) {

            datepicker.regional['pt-BR'] = {
                closeText: 'Fechar',
                prevText: '&#x3C;Anterior',
                nextText: 'Próximo&#x3E;',
                currentText: 'Hoje',
                monthNames: ['Janeiro','Fevereiro','Março','Abril','Maio','Junho',
                'Julho','Agosto','Setembro','Outubro','Novembro','Dezembro'],
                monthNamesShort: ['Jan','Fev','Mar','Abr','Mai','Jun',
                'Jul','Ago','Set','Out','Nov','Dez'],
                dayNames: ['Domingo','Segunda-feira','Terça-feira','Quarta-feira','Quinta-feira','Sexta-feira','Sábado'],
                dayNamesShort: ['Dom','Seg','Ter','Qua','Qui','Sex','Sáb'],
                dayNamesMin: ['Dom','Seg','Ter','Qua','Qui','Sex','Sáb'],
                weekHeader: 'Sm',
                dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
                firstDay: 0,
                isRTL: false,
                showMonthAfterYear: false,
                yearSuffix: ''};
            datepicker.setDefaults(datepicker.regional['pt-BR']);

            return datepicker.regional['pt-BR'];

            }));
            /* Brazilian Portuguese translation for the jQuery Timepicker Addon */
            /* Written by Diogo Damiani (diogodamiani@gmail.com) */
            (function ($) {
                $.timepicker.regional['pt-BR'] = {
                    timeOnlyTitle: 'Escolha o horÃ¡rio',
                    timeText: 'HorÃ¡rio',
                    hourText: 'Hora',
                    minuteText: 'Minutos',
                    secondText: 'Segundos',
                    millisecText: 'Milissegundos',
                    microsecText: 'Microssegundos',
                    timezoneText: 'Fuso horÃ¡rio',
                    currentText: 'Agora',
                    closeText: 'Fechar',
                    timeFormat: 'HH:mm',
                    amNames: ['a.m.', 'AM', 'A'],
                    pmNames: ['p.m.', 'PM', 'P'],
                    isRTL: false
                };
                $.timepicker.setDefaults($.timepicker.regional['pt-BR']);
            })(jQuery);

        });
    </script>
```